# Cocoa Memory Leak in NSTextFieldCell drawWithFrame?

Tags: macos, cocoa, memory-leaks

I have a complex app with lots of UI that updates/refreshes regularly without any user actions. It appears there is a memory leak caused by the redrawing of controls. In this particular case I think it is NSTextFieldCell inside of a table. The redraws are occurring because the underlying bound values are updated.

Below is an Instruments Call Tree showing the "created and persistent" memory after letting it run for 2 hours. Based on the math (23K calls and 1.8 MB leaked) it looks like about 80 bytes are being leaked each time it is called. I'm not seeing my app methods in the callback, so I'm not sure how this could be my leak but I welcome other opinions on that. Anyone have any ideas or suggestions on how to further track this one down?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does the Leaks instrument show it has leaked? If so, it will give you a stack trace of where it's allocated.

Comment: The call stack image in the OP I believe is showing the leaks. It is showing the "created & persistent" allocations. I added another screen capture that further digs into rectForString

Comment: No, created and persistent means that it was created and still exists. A leak is an object (or other memory) that was created and exists *and is unreferenced anywhere*.  If these don't show up in leaks then they are still referenced by some owning object. And that may be the key to understanding why they're hanging around.

Comment: I understand that, but in this context it is a call to NSTextFieldCell drawWithFrame that is allocating the object and then never releasing it. How is that not a memory leak in Cocoa? Every time it draws it is holding on to about 80 bytes.

Comment: If you've found an object that's leaking, you're 80% there. Examine *all* of the memory events associated with this object (create/retain/release/autorelease)—you may need to change your instrument settings to capture these. Also take a look at the debug memory graph feature of the recent Xcode versions; it will show you who actually has a reference to your object, not just where it was created/retained. If you don't have any references to it, it could be a straight-up under-release bug, so look towards non-ARC code and foundation for the problem.

Comment: Also note that there are probably a million ways a leak won't show your code in its callback trace. For example, you code retains an object and then returns. Some other code *doesn't* release it. You have a memory leak, but your code is no where to be found in the call tree. That's why looking at each event (alloc/retain/release/autorelease) is important; recreate the lifecycle of the objet and then figure out what the life cycle *should* be and compare it with what's actually happening.

Comment: Final comment: If you're using ARC, this can be a maddening exercise as ARC has tons of optimizations and shortcuts that defy our normal expectations about retains and release. Just saying...